# The "change page layout" button doesn't do anything when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

So, I should preface this by saying that I'm not an expert coder. In fact, I'm taking a computer science class and currently I only know HTML, CSS, and some Javascript. This has stumped me.

So, when I push that button at the bottom with the ID "btn1", it's supposed to trigger the changeLayout function. I plan to add more to the function later, but right now I've added a piece of code to write "hi" in the text box with the ID "firstname" to test if it works.
Except, when I push the button, nothing happens.
So far I've tried changing the button from an input type of button to just a button tag, I've tried changing the ID and function names multiple times, I've tried changing the .value to a .innerHTML in the function, and nothing has worked so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function mouseOver () {
        window.alert('Click here to accept cookies!')
    }
    function bannedKey () {
        window.alert('Sorry, that is a banned key. Please try again.')
    }
    function changeLayout(form) {
        document.getElementbyId("firstname").value = "hi"
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <fieldset>
        <b>First Name: </b><input type="text" name="keyjoke" onkeypress="bannedKey()" id="firstname" value=""><br>
        <b>Last Name: </b><input type="text" name="keyjoke" onkeypress="bannedKey()"><br>
        <button onmouseover="mouseOver()">Submit!</button>
        </fieldset><br>
        <input type="button" id="btn1" onclick="changeLayout(this.form)" value="Click here to change the page layout!">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be beneficial to add `"use strict";`  at the top of your JS code and check the console for errors. It likely would have made this obvious and easy to identify. Even without it, this error shows up in the console as a type error that `getElementbyId` is not a function. I'm not trying to be a smart alec but only pointing out sometthing that may help you out a great deal in the future in debugging your code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not "getElementbyId".  It's "getElementById"  (capital B in "By").

> document.getElementById("firstname").value = "hi"